# Serial connection via 3.5 mm Jack

Tags: arduino, usb, serial, uart, intel

lately I have been experimenting with the Intel Galileo, the thing is that I can't get the serial connection to work so I can do the "Linux magic". Today I bought this cable and tried to establish a UART connection but this error pops out. Any clews?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That cable does not provide a UART connection. Instead it connects the USB port directly to the TRRS plug. This is not what you want. Buy or make a real USB-to-UART bridge cable instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying but what's the difference between using that cable and a combination between these two cables http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004T9BBJC/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-RS-232-Serial-Converter-TU-S9/dp/B0007T27H8/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1384968482&sr=1-1&keywords=usb+serial+adapter ?

Comment: The difference is that the cable you have doesn't convert the signals from USB *at all*.

Comment: The thing is that I'm in Tunisia and I'm tight on budget, and I can't find any of the two other cables here so is there a third way to make a serial connection? Can I make the cable?

Comment: If you have a bridge then you can make the cable. Simply take the bridge and attach a TRS/TRRS plug as appropriate. You can even use the bridge of a e.g. Arduino Uno if you pull the MCU. Just make sure the voltages match.